# References in C++ with malloc

Tags: c++, reference, malloc

How can we use the references in C++ with `malloc()` ? , Can we take the heap memory for a reference ?

```
int &a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int);
```

Comment: int* a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

Comment: or in full `c++` style: `auto a = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int)));`

Answer (score 3):

> How can we use the references in C++ with malloc() ?

You can, sort of.  Whether or not you *should* is another question (and the answer to that question is, you almost certainly *shouldn't*)

> Can we take the heap memory for a reference ?

You can create a reference from a pointer, similar to your example code:

```
int * ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
int & ret = *ptr;
```

... or even:

```
int & ret = *((int *) malloc(sizeof(int)));
```

... but that is a very odd thing to do, and it is very likely that coding in that style will at some point result in a memory leak, since most programmers will not find it obvious that they are supposed to delete a reference.  (although it's also possible to do that by converting the reference to a pointer, e.g. delete &ret; )